# how to loop kruskal wallis test through different groups then print results

Tags: r, loops, group-by

I have a sample dataset that looks like this :

```
Day<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Group<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Value<-c(4,4,6,5,3,4,5,5,3,6,6,6,5,3,3,3,2,5,2)

d<-data.frame(Day,Group,Value)
```

I would like to do a Kruskal Wallis test between A, B and C in the "Group" variable for each "Day", then to print the results?
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute-force, you can use the `subset=` argument of `kruskal.test`:

```r
kruskal.test(Value ~ Group, data = d, subset = Day == 1)
#   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
# data:  Value by Group
# Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.5045, df = 2, p-value = 0.777
```

(and again for day 2).

But this is unsatisfying when there are many days, or the number of distinct days it not known a priori.

Here's another option, that does each day independently and returns all in one list:

```r
ret <- by(d, d$Day, function(z) kruskal.test(Value ~ Group, data = z))
names(ret)
# [1] "1" "2"
ret
# d$Day: 1
#   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
# data:  Value by Group
# Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.5045, df = 2, p-value = 0.777
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# d$Day: 2
#   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
# data:  Value by Group
# Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 6.5202, df = 2, p-value = 0.03839
```

And you can get the results from one of the multiple tests with `ret[["1"]]`. (Note that while *in this case* `ret[[1]]` and `ret[["1"]]` will be referring to the same element of the list, they are often different things. If your data spanned from `Day` 2 to 3 instead of 1 to 2, for example, then `ret[[2]]` would actually refer to `ret[["3"]]`. This is the reason why I showed the output from `names(ret)` above, to show that the index names are always strings, regardless if the actual `Day` values are integers or numerics.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rstatix` package which provides a pipe-friendly framework to perform Kruskal-Wallis rank-sum test. Wrapper around the function `kruskal.test()`.

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

Day<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Group<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Value<-c(4,4,6,5,3,4,5,5,3,6,6,6,5,3,3,3,2,5,2)

d<-data.frame(Day,Group,Value)

d %>% 
  group_by(Day) %>% 
  kruskal_test(Value ~ Group)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
    Day .y.       n statistic    df      p method        
* <dbl> <chr> <int>     <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>         
1     1 Value     9     0.505     2 0.777  Kruskal-Wallis
2     2 Value    10     6.52      2 0.0384 Kruskal-Wallis
```

which is same as provided by @andrew_reece but with much easier coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution.  Group by `Day`, fit K-W test as a list-column, then `unnest_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

d %>% 
  group_by(Day) %>% 
  summarise(fit = list(kruskal.test(Value ~ Group) %>% tidy)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(fit)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 5
    Day statistic p.value parameter method                      
  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                       
1     1     0.505  0.777          2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
2     2     6.52   0.0384         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
```